# How to find a function of a class by its name in python?

Tags: python

I mean , for example, in the following code I want to call prin in pre by name, but how?

`class a(object):`

`def __init__(self):`

```
    self.zz=1

    self.aa='hello'

def prin(self):

    print 'hello'

def pre(self,name):

    #if name is 'prin' then call self.prin
```

`if __name__ == '__main__':`

```
az = a()

az.pre('prin')`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getattr`

```
def pre(self,name):
    # name being 'prin' in your case
    if hasattr(self, name):
        getattr(self, name)()
```